# AWS health check status alarm reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services

> You do not have sufficient IAM permissions to create or use an existing IAM role.
>
> Fail to create instance status check alarm reboot : EC2ActionsAccess IAM role.

Does someone knows what permission do I need to add for this?

Comment: Are you the root user of the account?

Answer (score 0):

Do you can examined policies of IAM groups? So, you can saw in which group added your account and then checked their policies what allowed for its. All your possibility is into group policies.